# Fade in div AFTER page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following code:

```
function getValues(){
    var heat =  document.forms["toolSection"]["heatingType"].value;
    var meter = document.forms["toolSection"]["meterType"].value;
    var beds = document.forms["toolSection"]["noBedrooms"].value;
    var property = document.forms["toolSection"]["houseType"].value;
    var age = document.forms["toolSection"]["houseAge"].value;

    if (heat === null || heat=== ""){
      alert ("Please select your heating type.");
      return false;
    }
    if(meter === null || meter=== ""){
      alert ("Please select your meter type.");
      return false;
    }
    if(beds === null || beds === ""){
      alert ("Please select the number of bedrooms.");
      return false;
    }
    if(property === null || property === ""){
      alert ("Please select your property type.");
      return false;
    }
    if(age === null || age === ""){
      alert ("Please select the age of your property.");
      return false;
    } else {
      alert("Calculating a typical consumption value for you.");
      setTimeout(function () { 
        window.location.reload();
        }, 10);
      return true;
    }
  }
```

It basically checks if any of my form elements are empty and if they are then to display an alert warning the user to make sure that something is selected. Initially i had an issue where, when i clicked submit i was unable to see the calculate value until i refreshed the form, hence the `setTimeout(function () {` code. Now i was just wondering if its possible to load in a div AFTER the `setTimeout` function?

Code to show the hidden div:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $("#btn-calcCon").on('click', function() {
     $("#conContainer").fadeIn();
   });
  });
```

Thanks!

Comment: No, but you can load the div after page load based on some condition (or a URL parameter, or whatever).

Comment: Hmm currently the page refreshes once i hit submit. But i want the div to only appear AFTER the refresh, not just when i hit submit and shown the alerts.

Comment: You can't use JavaScript to tell the browser what to do in a future page. It's not possible for technical and security reasons. Instead, do a check for some condition on *every* page load.

Comment: Okay ill have a go at that. Do you have any suggestions on where i should start?

Comment: Check my answer @MoA, hope it helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Now i was just wondering if its possible to load in a div AFTER the setTimeout function?** - No you can't.

This is because the page will reload. You can however load in the div within the script of the reloaded page by setting something to trigger it like a variable or parameter as stated by @isherwood.

A solution:

```
function getValues() {
  var heat = document.forms["toolSection"]["heatingType"].value;
  var meter = document.forms["toolSection"]["meterType"].value;
  var beds = document.forms["toolSection"]["noBedrooms"].value;
  var property = document.forms["toolSection"]["houseType"].value;
  var age = document.forms["toolSection"]["houseAge"].value;

  if (heat === null || heat === "") {
    alert("Please select your heating type.");
    return false;
  }
  if (meter === null || meter === "") {
    alert("Please select your meter type.");
    return false;
  }
  if (beds === null || beds === "") {
    alert("Please select the number of bedrooms.");
    return false;
  }
  if (property === null || property === "") {
    alert("Please select your property type.");
    return false;
  }
  if (age === null || age === "") {
    alert("Please select the age of your property.");
    return false;
  } else {
    alert("Calculating a typical consumption value for you.");
    setTimeout(function() {
      // set a hash
      window.location.hash = "trigger_here";
      window.location.reload();
    }, 10);
    return true;
  }
}

// check if there is ANY hash
if (window.location.hash) {
  // remove the hash
  window.location.hash = "";
  // load your div using code here
  $("#conContainer").fadeIn();
}
```

This will set the hash on the url e.g. http://yourwebsite.com/example.html#trigger_here. You can check if it has the hash in the url and then load in your div if it does.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, however im not 100% sure what `window.location.hash` actually does

Comment: @MoA Can you mark the question as answered if it answered the original question: Now i was just wondering if its possible to load in a div AFTER the setTimeout function?

Comment: Thank you that makes sense, however im still unsure on how to display the hidden div

Comment: @MoA See my updated code :), if you need to discuss further then we should move this discussion to a chat

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109721/discussion-between-mo-a-and-papakia).